# Connect local postgres database from PGAdmin Container

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, localhost, pgadmin

I am trying to connect to my local postgres database from PGadmin in container, but it is through following error:

```
Unable to connect to Server: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed. connection refused is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

configurations i am trying for creating server are as follows:

```
hostname/address = localhost
port = 5432
username = postgres
```

my OS configurations

```
OS = Linux- Ubuntu
Version = 18.04
```

PS: there are some existing questions regarding this on Stackoverflow, but no solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

While it runs locally, the docker container is like a different machine. You need to put the IP address of the local host machine instead of localhost.

Comment: It shoes the error: Unable to connect to server: connection to server at xx.xx.xx.xx port 5432 failed. timeout expired

Comment: Yes, because there is no server running at xx.xx.xx.xx port 5432